# Require Help in XSLT coding

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT .Kindly help me with the below query :

**My Source XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:Header1 xmlns:ns1="urn:src:abc">
<Header2>
<Header3>
<field1>1.1.2017</field1>
<field2>12</field2>
<field3> </field3>
</Header3>
</Header2>
</ns1:Header1>
```

**Target/Expected XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:Header1 xmlns:ns2="urn:tar:abc" xmlns:v1="def.v1">
<Header2>
<v1:Header3>
<field1>1.1.2017</field1>
<field2>12</field2>
<field3> </field3>
</v1:Header3>
</Header2>
</ns2:Header1>
```

And also i need to remove the space/blank between the tag filed3 ( Field3 value sometimes will be blank)

I am using the below code for Transformation

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="*">
<ns2:Header1 xmlns:ns2="urn:tar:abc" xmlns:v1="def.v1">
<Header2> 
<xsl:copy-of select="//Header3"/>
</Header2>
</ns2:Header1>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not able to achieve my Target XML. Kindly help
Many thanks in advance
Regards,
Pavi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current template matches `*` which will match any element, but really you only want it to match the root element.

Additionally, as you want to change `Header3` from being in no namespace, to being in the "def.v1" namespace, you should be making use of `xsl:apply-templates`, not `xsl:copy-of`

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <ns2:Header1 xmlns:ns2="urn:tar:abc" xmlns:v1="def.v1">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </ns2:Header1>
</xsl:template>
```

You would then need a template matching `Header3` to change the namespace

```
<xsl:template match="Header3" xmlns:v1="def.v1">
    <v1:Header3>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </v1:Header3>
</xsl:template>
```

You would then just need the identity template to copy all other nodes without changes.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <ns2:Header1 xmlns:ns2="urn:tar:abc" xmlns:v1="def.v1">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ns2:Header1>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Header3" xmlns:v1="def.v1">
        <v1:Header3>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </v1:Header3>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action at http://xsltransform.net/jz1PuQb